# How to update xaxis and yaxis name on interval using Dash Plotly in python?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I copy the example from Dash-Plotly multiple inputs (https://dash.plot.ly/getting-started-part-2) and I changed it to be updated on intervals of 2 seconds. The graph is being updated but the title on the X and Y axis are not. The original example updates the X and Y titles on the graph. I am using python 3. I realized that this is happening only because I am using `dcc.Graph(id='indicator-graphic', animate=True),`. If I use `dcc.Graph(id='indicator-graphic'),` the xaxis and yaxis are updated but the graph itself no. Here is the code:

```
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Output, Input, Event
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

df = pd.read_csv(
    'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/chriddyp/'
    'cb5392c35661370d95f300086accea51/raw/'
    '8e0768211f6b747c0db42a9ce9a0937dafcbd8b2/'
    'indicators.csv')

available_indicators = df['Indicator Name'].unique()

# load file with all RPi available
available_rpi = pd.read_csv('available_rpi.conf', header=None, dtype={0: str}).set_index(0).squeeze().to_dict()
print("Raspberry Pi's available:")
for key, value in available_rpi.items():
    print('IP:{} name: {}'.format(key, value))
print()

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div([
        html.Div([
            dcc.Dropdown(
                id='xaxis-column',
                options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in available_indicators],
                value='Fertility rate, total (births per woman)'
            ),
            dcc.RadioItems(
                id='xaxis-type',
                options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in ['Linear', 'Log']],
                value='Linear',
                labelStyle={'display': 'inline-block'}
            )
        ],
        style={'width': '30%', 'display': 'inline-block'}),

        html.Div([
            dcc.Dropdown(
                id='yaxis-column',
                options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in available_indicators],
                value='Life expectancy at birth, total (years)'
            ),
            dcc.RadioItems(
                id='yaxis-type',
                options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in ['Linear', 'Log']],
                value='Linear',
                labelStyle={'display': 'inline-block'}
            )
        ],style={'width': '30%', 'float': 'right', 'display': 'inline-block'})
    ]),

    dcc.Graph(id='indicator-graphic', animate=True),
    dcc.Interval(id='graph-update',interval=2*1000),

    dcc.Slider(
        id='year--slider',
        min=df['Year'].min(),
        max=df['Year'].max(),
        value=df['Year'].max(),
        marks={str(year): str(year) for year in df['Year'].unique()}
    )
])

@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('indicator-graphic', 'figure'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('xaxis-column', 'value'),
     dash.dependencies.Input('yaxis-column', 'value'),
     dash.dependencies.Input('xaxis-type', 'value'),
     dash.dependencies.Input('yaxis-type', 'value'),
     dash.dependencies.Input('year--slider', 'value')],
     events=[Event('graph-update', 'interval')])
def update_graph(xaxis_column_name, yaxis_column_name,
                 xaxis_type, yaxis_type,
                 year_value):
    dff = df[df['Year'] == year_value]

    return {
        'data': [go.Scatter(
            x=dff[dff['Indicator Name'] == xaxis_column_name]['Value'],
            y=dff[dff['Indicator Name'] == yaxis_column_name]['Value'],
            text=dff[dff['Indicator Name'] == yaxis_column_name]['Country Name'],
            mode='markers',
            marker={
                'size': 15,
                'opacity': 0.5,
                'line': {'width': 0.5, 'color': 'white'}
            }
        )],
        'layout': go.Layout(
            xaxis={
                'title': xaxis_column_name,
                'type': 'linear' if xaxis_type == 'Linear' else 'log'
            },
            yaxis={
                'title': yaxis_column_name,
                'type': 'linear' if yaxis_type == 'Linear' else 'log'
            },
            margin={'l': 40, 'b': 40, 't': 10, 'r': 0},
            hovermode='closest'
        )
    }

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to https://community.plot.ly/t/my-callback-is-updating-only-the-lines-of-the-graph-but-not-the-legend/16208/3?u=felipe.o.gutierrez there is a lot of issues with `animate=True` and they are replacing for [Exploring a "Transitions" API for dcc.Graph 2](https://community.plot.ly/t/exploring-a-transitions-api-for-dcc-graph/15468)